# How to find the current route pattern in Symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Like in security.yml `- { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` I want to execute a code in an eventListener while the route pattern is deferent than `/admin`

Comment: Please show us some code and where it fails. I don't think we can help you without more details.

Comment: There is no fails, i just want to know how to get the current patter of a route. Like for example: 
Il (current_route_patter != "^/admin") { // execute code }

Answer (score 1):

If you are listening to a Symfony Kernel-event you will be able to retrieve the current request from the event by calling `getRequest()` on the event. You might have to check if it's the current request, i.e. you are not dealing with a sub-request, but I will omit this here.

Once you have the request checking if a route matches a pattern or is not captured by the pattern is as easy as doing a `preg_match()` or in simpler cases just a string comparison like this:

```
if (strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/admin/') === 0) {
    return
}

// Do your thing
```

This will skip the event when your route starts with `/admin/` and execute whatever you put instead of the comment if it does *not* match this admin pattern.

If you want to check if a certain route name has matched you can also fetch the `_route` attribute from the request:

```
$routeName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

You can then check the router for additional info on that route, deal with route names, e.g. by checking a certain prefix and do whatever else you want.